# Manjaro: Module vboxdrv not found

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, manjaro

I upgraded the system and did

> sudo pacman -S virtualbox virtualbox-host-modules virtualbox-guest-iso
> virtualbox-host-dkms
>
> yaourt virtualbox-ext-oracle
>
> sudo depmod -a
>
> sudo modprobe vboxdrv
>
> modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I followed tutorials on the web and youtube videos, instead of reading [manjaro wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Virtualbox).

The correct way of doing it is not to install virtualbox `virtualbox-host-modules`, instead of that, first I should check kernel version `uname -r` in my case I'm using `3.16.7.10-1-MANJARO` so I have to do

`sudo pacman -S linux316-virtualbox-host-modules`

As time goes on, blogs get more and more popular, they get better ranked, leaving official documentation way behind and users like me get false information. Anyway, hopefully my answer helps future users.

Answer (score 3):

These are the simplified steps:

The firt step you should be super user.

```
pacman -S linux-headers
pacman -S virtualbox virtualbox-guest-iso
modprobe vboxdrv
```

…but if you do not want to do manually at each startup:

open the file

```
 vim /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf
```

add to the current file

```
vboxdrv
```

Add usernames to the vboxusers group

```
gpasswd -a $USER vboxusers
```

Troubleshooting[/b:8wk2jz3u]

If you put the network adapter in bridged mode

```
modprobe -a vboxdrv vboxnetadp vboxnetflt
```

or if you do not want to do manually at each startup:

```
vim /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf

vboxnetadp
vboxnetflt
```

[Thanks to hector for the clear and good answer](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/818/can-t-run-my-vitualbox/4)

Answer (score 1):

A reboot fixed the problem for me.

The problem was that I've updated the kernel and did not reboot since then, so modprobe was still looking in the old path, and obviously could not find the modules it was looking for.

Comment: Cleve, when you do a `pacman -Syu` everything can be upgraded, and that includes `kernel` also.